# How to open search result in a new window?

Tags: html

I’ve been trying to get search results to open in a new window for hours now, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

```
<form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="http://www.maps.google.com" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120">     
  <input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">
</form>
```

Edit: Adding the CSS here

```
#tfnewsearch{
    float:right;
    padding:20px;
}
.tftextinput{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
.tfbutton {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tfbutton:hover {
    text-decoration: none;

}
/* Fixes submit button height problem in Firefox */
.tfbutton::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

Anybody that sees what's wrong?

Comment: New window or new tab?

Comment: `_blank` seems to only open new tab in the latest browsers

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it right. I've copied and pasted your code and test it and it works fine, check your css clases, or that your are not missing any label to be closed

Comment: I couldn't see anything, maybe I'm just blind at the moment for starring at it for hours. Added the CSS code in the question